# Linking a form to log as an activity on an individual's profile

Tags: forms, formbuilder

I am trying to create a new form to log health and safety accidents linked to an individual that will work as an online accident book that reports can be pulled from.
I would like to link the form to existing individuals so that it is stored on their profile as an activity.  I have created an activity type for this.

How to I link the form to an individual? On form builder I have opted for existing individual but seem to be missing a step.
Have you used Civi for accident reporting and would you recommend an alternative way to log?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to SE!  From the FormBuilder main page, click the arrow next to `New Submission Form` and select `Activity` to create a new form.

- Click on the `Activity 1` tab
- It should show `Added by` `Select Current User` - that makes sense: the person to be recorded as the creator of the activity is the current user when the form is filled in.
- In the `Activity Type` box, select the activity type you created for Accident Reports.
- You probably want to drag the `Details` field on the right pane so users can describe what happened, and may also add `Assigned to` in the `Values` section and add the name of your Health & Safety person so they receive an email when a new accident report is submitted.
- You also want to record who is involved in the accident: (I think this is the bit you're missing)

  - A) You could assume that the person filling in the report was involved, so:

    - Under the `Values` section where it says `Add value`, click that and select `With Contacts`.
    - Click in the new `With Contacts` box and then on `Select Current User`
    - This won't show in the form the end-user sees but will set the fields on the CiviCRM activity.
      [image]
  - B) Alternatively, you can let the person filling in the form select the people involved:

    - Click on `With Contacts` under the list of `Activity Fields` and drag it on to the right pane near `Subject`
    - The user filling in the form can then select multiple people (including themselves) who were involved in the accident.
      [image]

Note that you don't need an `Individual` tab on the form if you only select existing contacts.